# How to create dynamic query with for loop?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010

I want to create query dynamically based on entered number and make it to *array* to get data from view, so I can create condition to filter it, but my query only works for **3** entered numbers.

```
var query = from bs in dc.VwResourceAssignments select bs;

var listReqNumber = new[] {123, 456, 789};
```

My current query is:

```
if (listReqNumber.Length == 1)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[0]));
}
else if (listReqNumber.Length == 2)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[0]) ||
                             p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[1]));
}
else if (listReqNumber.Length == 3)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[0]) ||
                             p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[1]) ||
                             p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[2]));
}
```

Is there any way to make it dynamically so I can input requisition number as many as I want?

Comment: i would recommend searching for a predicatebuilder class - this is a solved problem so you should be in luck

Comment: is that works on visual studio 2010??

Comment: you should not be using vs2010.  we are now reaching the end of 2018 with vs 2019 already in preview.  strongly recommend you upgrade

Comment: im still developing old project that use vs 2010,,

Comment: ok, i have submitted change to tags to add vs2010 as that is important to you in this question.  i can't help you though - good luck

Comment: `.Where(p => listReqNumber.Any(req => p.Contains(req)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's *generalize* the problem: if we have an *arbitrary* `listReqNumber` array we want to implement

```
query = query.Where(
   p => p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[0]) ||
        p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[1]) || 
        ...
        p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[listReqNumber.Length - 1])
);
```

or - let's get rid of `||` - we want `any` item `req` withing `listReqNumber` be contained in `p.RequisitionNumber`

```
 // doesn't compile - just the idea   
 query = query.Where(p => p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(any req in listReqNumber));
```

Pity, we can't put `any req in listReqNumber` but we can *swap* `listReqNumber` and `p.RequisitionNumber` and finally have a valid query:

```
 query = query.Where(p => listReqNumber.Any(req => p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(req)));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you use directly like this:

```
var result = from p in query where listReqNumber.Contains(p.RequisitionNumber) select p;
```

Comment: Or to use the syntax you're already using `var result = query.Where(p => listReqNumber.Contains(p.RequisitionNumber);`

Comment: i have tried it before, but its work if RequisitionNumber exactly same, for example, data in database is 45321 , the number that i enter is 453, then the result is nothing, I have to enter exactly 45321, any idea for my chase?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var data = query.Where(q =>
  q.RequisitionNumber.Any(w => listReqNumber.Contains(w))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic linq. Link is here: 
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

then have a function like below:

```
string GetQuery(int num)
{
    return $"p.RequisitionNumber.Contains(listReqNumber[{num}])";
}
```

Create a query like below in Main:

```
string testQuery = string.Empty; // or use StringBuilder then convert to string.
int length = 4;
for (int temp = 1; temp <= length; temp ++)
     testQuery += testQuery.Length == 0 ? GetQuery(temp - 1) : " || " + GetQuery(temp);
```

then use dynamic linq like:

```
var query = northwind.Products
                         .Where(testQuery).OrderBy("SupplierID");
```